# Determining what minimal jars are needed for a feature

Tags: java, frameworks, jar

How do you determine what jars are needed for such and such feature of a framework? For example, what jars would be needed out of all those available for Spring in order to support only dependency injection?

Comment: Test, test, test.

But usually if framework says it needs all jars, you better provide all the jars, otherwise you are on your own.

Comment: An example is Spring. Nearly all it's third party dependencies are marked as optional in the Maven POM. I agree that testing is the "catch-all" for this, but it's a good question - I've often wished for a way to know at runtime which libraries are actually used.

I've used a Java Ahead-of-Time Native Compiler - this recorded all the classes used and the jars that they came from. You could emulate something similar with a custom class loader that tracks the classes loaded and uses Class.getResource() to determine the location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are tools that create minimal JARs by figuring out which classes are actually used in an application by statically analyzing the code, then creating a new JAR containing only those classes. (I recall using Zelix Classmaster to do this, but there are many alternatives.)

The problem with using these tools for a DI framework like Spring include:

- The existing only trace static dependencies.  If you dynamically load classes, you have to specifically tell the analyser about each one.  DI frameworks in general, and Spring in particular is replete with dynamic loading, including dynamic loading that is opaque to application code.
- The existing tools work by creating a new output JAR, not by telling you which of the input JARs are not used.  While repackaging the JARs is OK if you are creating a shrink-wrapped application from a closed-source codebase, it is undesirable in general, and potentially problematic with some open-source licenses.  Certainly you don't want to do this with Spring.

In theory, someone could write a tool to help.  In practice, the tool would need to (for example) know how to extract dynamic class dependencies from Spring configurations expressed in annotations, XML and from bean descriptors created at runtime from higher order configuration (SpringSecurity does this for example).  That is a big ask.  And even then you have the problem that a "small" change to the wirings made on the installation platform could fail due to a required JARs having been left out by the JAR pruning process.

In my view, the more practical alternatives are:

- If you use Maven / Ivy to manage your dependencies, look at the dependency graphs, strip out dependencies that appear to be no longer needed ... and test, test, test.
- Manually strip out JARs that appear to be unused ... and test, test, test.
- Don't worry about it.  A moderate level of unused JAR cruft might add a second or three to deployment and webapp startup times, but that generally doesn't matter.  (But if it does ... see above.)

Comment: [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net) is another example which can do that (and more).

Comment: @BalusC - and there are undoubtedly other worthy examples.  But unfortunately, they don't really address *this* problem.

Comment: I was referring to the 1st paragraph :) Before you edited the practical alternatives in, which I however fully agree (+1).

Answer (score 1):

This is why some older Java projects end up having 600 Jars and a 200 MB war file, for a 10,000 line application. Kind of a pain if you don't manage it carefully...

Answer (score 0):

You should really ask the framework provider or read the documentation. Statically analyzing what jars are required might not be enough in some cases(dynamic loading) and sometimes you might end up with too many jars.

I once did some ftp helper stuff to a sort of "utility" library. It depended on some apache ftp jar. If you never used the ftp features in the library you would not need the ftp jar but statical analysis of the code might say you need it. This is something you should documents.